# How to scale small imageview to fill large scrollview?

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, scale

How do you create a layout with a screen-filling scrollview that has a small image in an imageview scaled to fit the whole scrollview and be scrollable? eg. A 720x1280 display has a full-screen scrollview (fill_parent). Inside is a linearlayout (fill_parent). In that is a 300x900 bitmap in an imageview that is upscaled to 720x2160, fills the screen width and exceeds the vertical bounds, and can be scrolled up/down in the scrollview.

The solution should work for all screen sizes to support multiple devices from mobiles to tablets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="720dp"
            android:layout_height="2160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If you need to make this work for any screen size do it programmatically:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = width;
}
```

Comment: That would, but that solution only works for a fixed screen size. If the same app is run on a 600 x 1024 display, or 320 x 480 display, the image won't scale.

Comment: You would need to scale the ImageView programmatically, or provide different layouts. The ImageView needs to have the correct width and height layout params given to it. These will be different for different screen sizes.

Comment: Okay. That sucks. Seems Android is built around doing everything programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. I'm targeting 2.2 so getSize() won't working, but I should be able to tweak that

Comment: Yes, use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();`

Answer (score 0):

if scroll view height and width is fill parent  than if background is set with an small image it will automatically expand in your layout

Comment: That will scale the image to fit the screen, but not larger than the screen so it can be scrolled. I also want a buttonview after the imageview.

Comment: scrolling works but if you have no of elements thats total height greater than screen size and they are going out of screen

Comment: My scrollview only contains an image. Having a background image won't scale it suitably.